# Generalized Coupon Collector's Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expectation, harmonic-functions, coupon-collector

I just read about the coupon collector's problem where you're trying to find out how many coupons you need to collect on average before you get one complete set. This turns out to be $nH(n)$. I was wondering, how would you go about generalizing this problem to figure out how many coupons you would need on average to get N complete sets?

Comment: This usually goes by the name "the double Dixie cup problem". A search on that should bring up a treasure trove of references, including (humbly) my article: http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v15i1n31 .